# Manage Azure SQL Databases

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

For some reason the SQL Management Tool doesnt work with Azure SQL Databases. This is nothing short of painful if you use the designers and diagrams to design your database.

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has stumbled at this point and would like to know what tool I can use to visual design and maintain the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest update to SSMS supports full design and edit with a few minor things missing.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Management Studio supports Azure SQL DB.  Step-by-step docs are here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-azure-ssms/

You will have problems if you have not configured firewall rules for your database to include your client IP range.  What sort of errors are you experiencing?

Comment: No it doesn't. It supports connections and lets you run SQL statements but doesnt support any of the design options. Which is very disapointing given its Microsoft Tool and Microsoft Service, where the same tool works with AWS RDS.